# Metrics not being reported, but JVm stats are

Tags: metrics, pom.xml, yammer, graphite

Hia All,

I have a service which is pushing metrics to Graphite.  However, it is only pushing the JVM metrics, not the info metrics.

When I hit the URL:

`http://myservice.com/mypath/info/metrics`

I get what I expect, jvm and info metrics.  i.e:

```
`{
    "jvm":{
        "vm":{
            "name":"Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM",
            "version":"1.6.0_12-b04"
        },
        ... removed for brevity_
        }
    },
    "info.application":{
        "myMethod":{
            "type":"counter",
            "count":0
        },
        "doPost":{
           ... removed for brevity_
        }
    }
}`
```

I can see both the JVM metrics and the info metrics there, however, only the JVM metrics are showing in Graphite.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is causing this?

All help gratefully received!

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enabled the graphite reporter

```
GraphiteReporter.enable(metricsRegistry, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, graphiteHost, graphitePort, hostname);
```

And bound all the listeners to the registry.

```
bindListener(Matchers.any(), new MeteredListener(metricsRegistry));
bindListener(Matchers.any(), new TimedListener(metricsRegistry));
bindListener(Matchers.any(), new GaugeListener(metricsRegistry));
```